# Why is this code causing an SQL error?

Tags: database

I wrote code to select records from the database, but it is causing the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
>       in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
>       right syntax to use near 'FROM pricepackages pricepackages' at line 1: SELECT FROM 
>       {pricepackages} pricepackages; Array ( ) in view_packages() (line 25 of D:\xampp\htdocs
>       \talyllyn\sites\all\modules\pricepackages\pricepackages.module).

What is wrong with the code I am using?

```
function view_packages() {
    $list = '<table>';
    $query = db_select('pricepackages')->execute();
    $i = 0;

    while ($record = $query->fetchAssoc()) {
        $list .= '<tr><td>';
        $list .= $record['packageName']."</td>";
        $list .= '<td>'.$record['packageDescp']."</td>";
        $list .= '<td>'.$record['pPrice']."</td>";
        $list .= '</tr>';
        $i++;
    }

    $list .= '</table>';
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: First comment on drupal api db_select page should provide the answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your current query as it's executed:

```
SELECT 
FROM 
{pricepackages} pricepackages
```

Which is obviously wrong; an SQL `SELECT` query needs one or more fields. To `SELECT *`:

```
$query = db_select('pricepackages')->fields('pricepackages')->execute();
```

Or specific fields:

```
$fields = array('foo', 'bar');
$query = db_select('pricepackages')->fields('pricepackages', $fields)->execute();
```

Comment: Always look in the Drupal APIs documentation, you can find useful examples there. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7